# Regex multiline matching

Tags: iphone, ios, regex, cocoa-touch

I was wondering if it's possible to make a regular expression to find all of the text that is in between the following two strings:

```
mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
...
CGPathAddPath(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath);
```

Basically, the first and last lines will always be the same, and there will be a whole bunch of random stuff in between. I'm using the find feature in xCode and would like to count the number of lines that appear between all instances of the first and last line from above.

Is this even possible?

Comment: This isn't really the proper application of regex, seeing as the input is not regular (you could do it, but the chances of it failing under some circumstances are high)

Comment: Or you can user some specialized text editor like BBEdit to face this amazing stuff. :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - How would I be able to accomplish that with BBEdit? (just curious)

Comment: first replace "mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();" with "//@@###\n mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();" and then replace "CGPathAddPath(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath);" with "CGPathAddPath(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath);\n//@@###"   Here //@@### will help you to search in entire file... rest you know what to do :)

Comment: kindly inform me if this worked?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - Thanks for your response. Not sure exactly what you mean, how will that help to search the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode does not support multi-line regex matching. You'll have to search for your first and last line and count the lines in between by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use the DOTALL modifier,

I was able to find a block of code like yours with this regex:

`(?s)mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable\(\);.+CGPathAddPath\(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath\);`

More info in the ICU regex documentation [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html)